# How to find the volume of this surface of evolution?

Tags: integration, volume, parametric

I don't know how to find the volume enclosed by this surface of revolution, obtained by revolving the region bounded by the curves
$$\begin{cases} x = 5\cos t \\ y=3\sin t \end{cases},\ x = 0,\ x = 2$$
about the line $ x=2$

[image]
What integral should I use? Help, please.

Comment: The 2D volume of this curve is zero. I assume you are looking for the length of it.

Comment: Do you care what's happening in the overlap region?

Comment: @Jack He's rotating an ellipse around an axis $x=2$. If $x$ would be greater than $5$, it would look like a doughnut

Comment: I need to find the volume of figure that is between parametric graph, axis = 0 and axis = 2  rotating around x=2

Comment: @Andrei: I misread the question. I shall delete my stupid comment then `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, rewrite the ellipse equation

$$ \frac{x^2}{25} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$$

or, in terms of $x$
$$ y = \pm 3 \sqrt{1 - \frac{x^2}{25}} $$

Using the cylindrical shell method, we add up shells with thichness $dx$, radius $r=2-x$ and height $h = 2|y| = 6\sqrt{1-\dfrac{x^2}{25}}$. The total volume is then

$$ V = \int 2\pi r h\ dx = 2\pi\int_0^2 6(2-x)\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{25}}\ dx $$

Answer (score 1):

The parametric equation that you have is the equation of an ellipse. Just eliminate $t$.
$$(x/5)^2=\cos^2t\\(y/3)^2=\sin^2t\\\left(\frac{x}{5}\right)^2+\left(\frac{y}{3}\right)^2=1$$
We can easily calculate the intersections of the ellipse with $x=2$, and you get two solutions, one positive, one negative: $y_{int}=\pm\frac{3}{5}\sqrt{21}$.

When you rotate your figure, you get a cylinder with some "dents" at the top and bottom. Each of these dents can be understood as made out of disks with radius $2-|x(y)|$ and thickness $dy$.
So the volume is $$V=\pi2^26-2V_{dent}$$
where $$V_{dent}=\int_{y_{int}}^3\pi(2-|x(y)|)^2dy$$ 
Just in case you did not guess $$x(y)=5\sqrt{1-y^2/9}$$

Answer (score 1):

Disks/washers or shells?

Lets go with shells.

$A = 2\pi \int xy  dx\\
x = 5\cos t\\
dx = -5\sin t \ dt\\
y = 3\sin t$

Limits $\arccos (\frac 25)$ to $\pi$

This is only half way around so I will need to double it.

$4\pi\displaystyle \int_{\arccos (\frac 25)}^{\pi} -75\sin^2 t\cos t  dt\\
4\pi (-25\sin^3 t)|_{\arccos (\frac 25)}^{\pi}\\
4\pi (25)(1-\frac {4}{25})^{\frac 32})\\
4\pi (\frac {21 \sqrt {21}}{5})$